# K modes clustering : how to choose the number of clusters?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, categorical-data, data-mining

I am looking for a proper method to choose the number of clusters for **K mode**s.

I tried to find the optimal number of clusters by maximizing the average silhouette width though.

In k-modes,  the average silhouette width increases with the increase of the number of clusters with my case.

So i tried to derive the elbow plot and I got the attached graph.

[image]

It is quite hard to which point is the location of a bend in this plot..

In this case, how can I choose the best number of groups?

and Can anyone introduce better method that help choose the optimal number of clusters for K-modes?

Comment: the graph is attached as above. :)

Comment: Hi @user3242742, what is the total within diff in your plot?

Comment: im facing the same problem. did you get the solution?

Comment: How did you determine the total within difference?

Answer (score 2):

The elbow is at 4.

Afterwards, the drop follows the usual behavior of random data and 1/x curves.

Since the elbow is not very prominent, the results likely are not very good, and you need to evaluate other preprocessing and clustering methods if they work better.

Comment: Thanks for comment. :) Now I see. I tried to use NbClust packages in R though, it does not provide "K-modes" method... Would you recommend other clustering method for categorical variables?

Comment: Categorical variables often don't cluster well. I'd consider frequent itemset mining.

Comment: Actually,  R _does_ provide k-modes in the klaR package.

Comment: @G5W yes I tried this with the klaR package though, it does not provide the additional method to support the decision to choose the proper number of clusters.